# Android C2DM Registration_ID max size

Tags: android, android-c2dm

What is the maximum possible size of the registration_id field used for Android C2DM service?

Comment: unfortunately there is no answer to this question..

Answer (score 9):

The max size for a `registration_id` is bounded by the max size for a cookie, which is 4K (4096 bytes).

In practice, the tokens are going to be much smaller than that, but you shouldn't rely on this behavior going forward.

(The `registration_id` is not considered part of the payload, so the footnote Reno mentioned doesn't apply here.)

Source: I'm on the Android team at Google. :)
(I'll be updating the docs soon to make this more clear, since there's been a few people asking recently.)

Comment: Hello, If you have time please check my question here about the registrationId pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403628/is-there-a-gcm-registrationid-pattern

Answer (score 2):

According to [This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_thread/thread/0141a5be624fc8c3) results vary (98 and 120 are given), but the poster recommends setting aside 255 in your database, and that's what I'm going with.

Answer (score 0):

<del>[As per the footnote at the bottom of this link.](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#example) it should be 1024 bytes at the most. Also this shouldn't be of concern if you are using Java.</del>

```
private void handleRegistration(Context context, Intent intent)
{
        String registration = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id"); 
      .... }
```

---

[edit]

Like Trevor says, the max size ought to be the size of a cookie. (4096 Bytes)

Comment: I think, the message size limit(at the link) is for the push message. It is just a presumption, that the registration id has the same limits.

Comment: Well you are right, Trevor who works for Google, has the right answer.