# Structure of GCM token

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've noticed that GCM tokens appear to use `:` only once, and always in the same (or close-to-same) position in a token string.  This suggests that it's a delimiter of some sort.  And that the parts on either side of the `:` have different meaning.  Would anyone know what the two parts represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this out for Android before and concluded that:

```
<first_part>:<second_part>
```

The *first part* is the ID for the app instance, which is why calling [`getId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getId()) returns the same value:

> Returns a stable identifier that uniquely identifies the app instance.

and the *second part* is the actual token for the corresponding *authorized entity* - i.e. sender project. Note that its possible for two different tokens to be generated from the same device, provided you are usimg multiple senders.

Comment: When you say `... its possible for two different tokens to be generated from the same device, provided you are usimg multiple senders.`, do you mean two sender projects sending notifications to the same app instance?

Comment: I've noticed that some tokens don't have an app instance id prefix.  Do you know if this is because in the past the tokens used to not include it?

Comment: For the two sender projects -- yes. For the app instance id prefix -- It's possible. This wasn't always the format for registration tokens before (back in GCM). So yeah, it could be a really old token. It was actually advised that [the token format is subject to change in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502351/4625829) so I didn't put too much thought into the structure anymore.